# Cross-client aggregating calendar application

Tags: cross-platform, calendar

I need a cross-client (Android, Win/Web) calendar application that can subscribe to online iCalendar files and where I can create new events with an efficient UI.

I've tried [Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar) and [Microsofts Live Calendar](https://calendar.live.com), but the problem there is that they both have ridiculously slow updating cycles (up to 24-hours) on external iCalendar resoures and you are not able to refresh them manually.

I also tried [Sunrise Calendar](https://calendar.sunrise.am/) but these people are obviously collecting as much private data they can while connecting to other resources, while not supporting direct subscriptions to ICal files. I don't want anything of that shady business.

[Cross-platform calendar that stores data locally - I want to sync it myself](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3103/cross-platform-calendar-that-stores-data-locally-i-want-to-sync-it-myself) is similar, but I'm ok with storing the data somewhere, just as long as it's not blatantly greedy like Sunrise on private data.

Comment: For Android, you can check [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general). As for privacy: I'm using ownCloud as storage (on my own machine, but there are also sites providing you your own installation as a service). This includes a web frontend, but also can be synced via CalDav. Would that be an acceptable solution for you?